# Access Configuration in playframework 2.1 from model

Tags: java, playframework-2.1

I'm trying to access a value in my application.conf file using:

```
Play.configuration.getString("value");
```

I get the error:

```
error: package Play does not exist
```

What do I need to import to access the conf file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This syntax looks like the Scala Api. For Java, you should use this method:

```
play.Play.application().configuration().getString("value");

// or
import play.Play;
Play.application().configuration().getString("value");
```

Answer (score 3):

or you can do

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;
ConfigFactory.load().getString("value");
```

for typesafe